# Raspberry Pi Python Tkinter image flicker problem

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

This is my first post and I have googled extensively for an answer but found nothing that works. I'm new to python but have some experience with C++/arduino programming.

I'm trying to make a weather station and display some garage door states as image icons. My issue is when it works, it flickers the images and eventually bogs down the system and runs very slowly. I've tried every combination I can think of making objects global or only changing certain parameters in the Label objects to work around the garbage collection issue I've read about. I've tried Canvas as well, but the issue I had with that is no matter what location coordinates I entered, it always showed up in the top center of the screen.

Edit: as per requested, heres a truncated version:

```
root = tk.Tk()

global garageOpenIcon
global garageClosedIcon
global doorUnlockedIcon
global doorLockedIcon
global doorOpenIcon

backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = "background.gif")
garageOpenIcon = PhotoImage(file = "garageOpen.gif")
garageClosedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "garageClosed.gif")
doorLockedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorLocked.gif")
doorUnlockedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorUnlocked.gif")
doorOpenIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorOpen.gif")

background = Label(root, image = backgroundImage)
background.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

global mainDoorLabel
global sideDoorLabel

mainDoorLabel = Label(root)
sideDoorLabel = Label(root)



def getDoors():
    global garageOpenIcon
    global garageClosedIcon
    global doorOpenIcon
    global doorUnlockedIcon
    global doorLockedIcon

    global mainDoorLabel
    global sideDoorLabel


    #side door open and unlocked:
    if(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
        sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorOpenIcon)


    #closed and unlocked:
    elif(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.LOW):
        if(GPIO.input(sideDoorLockPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
            sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorUnlockedIcon)

        elif(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.LOW):
            sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorLockedIcon)

    #main door:
    if(GPIO.input(mainDoorPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
        mainDoorLabel = Label(image = garageOpenIcon)

    else:
         mainDoorLabel = Label(image = garageClosedIcon)

    mainDoorLabel.place(x = 50, y = 400)
    sideDoorLabel.place(x = 150, y = 400)

    root.after(1000, getDoors)
```

Here is my full code, images work but flicker:

```
# WeatherStation for Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2
# steve.a.mccluskey@gmail.com
#
# Code adapted from youtube.com/watch?v=MWKAitSX3vg
# Channel educ8s.tv
# Video name "Raspberry Pi Project: Touch Weather Station using a DHT22 and a Raspberry Pi 3 with TKInter GUI
#
# This program uses readings from several Dallas DS18B20 temp sensors and displays on the LCD along with on a website.
# Temps are collected from a background process called updateSensors.py and written to a JSON file called sensorValues.JSON
# which is located in the web folder at /var/www/html/. This program reads the JSON file. The webpage also reads it so there's
# minimal interferance between programs.
# Sensors are zero indexed.  The sensors are assigned to their respective labels by their index number.
# Use readSensors.py to print their index number, digital ID and current temp to the console.
#
# Door sensors are read directly from this program and displayed accordingly. updateDoor.py is also run in background to write to doorSensorValues.json
# also in the web folder to be served to the web page.
#
# Hardware Used:
# Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2
# Adafruit PITFT - Assembled 480x320 3.5" TFT+Touchscreen For Raspberry Pi, adafruit.com/product/2097
# Adafruit Prototyping Pi Plate Kit for Raspberry Pi, adafruit.com/product/801
# Sparkfun RJ45 Breakout sparkfun.com/products/716
# Sparkfun RJ45 8-Pin Connector sparkfun.com/products/643
# Dallas OneWire DS18B20 Digital Temp Sensors
#
#
#
#
# ------------
# GPIO Pins used:
# 1 ) 3.3v      -> orange       -> 3.3v
# 2 ) 5.0v
# 3 ) SDA               -> white/brown  -> I2C SDA
# 4 ) 5.0v
# 5 ) SCL       -> brown        -> I2C SCL
# 6 ) Gnd       -> white/orange -> Gnd
# 7 ) GPIO 7 -> GPIO 4  -> white/green  -> OneWire Bus
# 8 ) TXD
# 9 ) Gnd
# 10) RXD
# 11) GPIO 0 -> GPIO 17
# 12) GPIO 1 -> GPIO 18
# 13) GPIO 2 -> GPIO 27 -> blue         -> Main Door Sensor
#
# 14) Gnd
# 15) GPIO 3 -> GPIO 22 -> white/blue   -> Side Door Sensor
# 16) GPIO 4 -> GPIO 23 -> green        -> Side Door Lock Sensor
# 17) 3.3v
# 18) GPIO 5 -> GPIO 24 -> LCD Shield
# 19) SPI MOSI          -> LCD Shield
# 20) Gnd
# 21) SPI MISO          -> LCD Shield
# 22) GPIO 6 -> GPIO 25 -> LCD Shield
# 23) SPI SCLK          -> LCD Shield
# 24) SPI CE0           -> LCD Shield
# 25) Gnd
# 26) SPI CE1           -> LCD Shield

# -------
# Cat5e Pinout :
# White/Orange : Gnd
# Orange       : 3.3v
# White/Green  : OneWire
# Blue         : Main Door Sensor
# White/Blue   : Side Door Sensor
# Green        : Side Door Lock Sensor
# White/Brown  : I2C SDA
# Brown        : I2C SCL


from   Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from   Tkinter import Canvas
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import threading
import tkFont
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import json
import time
import datetime

#temp sensor assignments:
livingRoom = 1
upstairs   = 4
basement   = 0
outside    = 2
garage     = 3
sammyDoor  = 5

#digital door sensor pins:
mainDoorPin     = 27
sideDoorPin     = 22
sideDoorLockPin = 23

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(mainDoorPin,     GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(sideDoorPin,     GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(sideDoorLockPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


root = tk.Tk()

global garageOpenIcon
global garageClosedIcon
global doorUnlockedIcon
global doorLockedIcon
global doorOpenIcon

backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = "background.gif")
garageOpenIcon = PhotoImage(file = "garageOpen.gif")
garageClosedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "garageClosed.gif")
doorLockedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorLocked.gif")
doorUnlockedIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorUnlocked.gif")
doorOpenIcon = PhotoImage(file = "doorOpen.gif")

background = Label(root, image = backgroundImage)
background.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

global mainDoorLabel
global sideDoorLabel
global mainDoorState
global sideDoorState

mainDoorLabel = Label(root)
sideDoorLabel = Label(root)

#mainDoorLabel.place(x = 50, y = 400)
#sideDoorLabel.place(x = 150, y = 400)


#temp sensor strings:
mainTemp = StringVar()
mainTemp.set("In: ")

mainTempValue = StringVar()

outTemp = StringVar()
outTemp.set("Out:")

LR = StringVar()
LR.set("Living Room: ")

temperatureLR = StringVar()

UP = StringVar()
UP.set("Upstairs: ")

temperatureUp = StringVar()

DN = StringVar()
DN.set("Basement: ")

temperatureDn = StringVar()

Out = StringVar()
Out.set("Outside: ")

temperatureOut = StringVar()

Garage = StringVar()
Garage.set("Garage: ")

temperatureGg = StringVar()

SammyDoor = StringVar()
SammyDoor.set("SammyDoor: ")

temperatureSammyDoor = StringVar()

currentTime = StringVar()
timeStamp = StringVar()

#temp sensor labels:
mainTempLabel = Label(root, fg = "magenta2", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = mainTemp, font = ("Helvetica", 30))
mainTempLabel.place(x = 20, y = 195)

mainTempValueLabel = Label(root, fg = "magenta2", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = mainTempValue, font = ("Helvetica", 62, "bold"))
mainTempValueLabel.place(x = 100, y = 170)

outTempLabel = Label(root, fg = "magenta2", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = outTemp, font = ("Helvetica", 30))
outTempLabel.place(x = 20, y = 300)

outTempValueLabel = Label(root, fg = "magenta2", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureOut, font = ("Helvetica", 62, "bold")) 
outTempValueLabel.place(x = 100, y = 260)

currentTimeLabel = Label(root, fg = "purple", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = currentTime, font = ("Helvetica", 30))
currentTimeLabel.place(x = 270, y = 5)

LRLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = LR, font = ("Helvetica", 25))
LRLabel.place(x = 391, y = 160)

temperatureLRLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureLR, font = ("Helvetica", 25, "bold"))
temperatureLRLabel.place(x = 600, y = 160)

UPLabel = Label(root, fg= "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = UP, font = ("Helvetica", 25))
UPLabel.place(x = 391, y = 210)

temperatureUpLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureUp, font = ("Helvetica", 25, "bold"))
temperatureUpLabel.place(x = 600, y = 210)

DNLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = DN, font = ("Helvetica", 25))
DNLabel.place(x = 391, y = 260)

temperatureDnLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureDn, font = ("Helvetica", 25, "bold"))
temperatureDnLabel.place(x = 600, y = 260)

GarageLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = Garage, font = ("Helvetica", 25))
GarageLabel.place(x = 391, y = 310)

temperatureGgLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureGg, font = ("Helvetica", 25, "bold"))
temperatureGgLabel.place(x = 600, y = 310)

SammyDoorLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = SammyDoor, font = ("Helvetica", 25))
SammyDoorLabel.place(x = 391, y = 360)

temperatureSammyDoorLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = temperatureSammyDoor, font = ("Helvetica", 25, "bold"))
temperatureSammyDoorLabel.place(x = 600, y = 360)

timeStampLabel = Label(root, fg = "white", background = "#00dbde", textvariable = timeStamp, font = ("Helvetica", 15))
timeStampLabel.place(x = 530, y = 440)



root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)


exitButton = tk.Button(root,fg = "white", text = "X", font = ("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), command = exit, bg = "red")
exitButton.place(x = 680, y = 0)

root.update_idletasks()

def exit():
    root.quit()


def updateTemps():
    index_value    = []
    id_value       = []
    temp_value     = []
    dateTime_value = []

    #try reading json file. will not read if it is being written to by background process updateSensors.py
    try:
        with open('/var/www/html/sensorValues.json', 'r') as f:
            data       = f.read()
            dataString = json.loads(data)
        f.close()

        for dateTime in dataString['timestamp']:
            dateTime_value = (dateTime['dateTime'])

        for index in dataString['sensors']:
            temp_value.append(index['temp'])
            id_value.append(index['id'])
            index_value.append(index['index'])

        temperatureLR.set(str(temp_value[livingRoom]) + " F")
        temperatureOut.set(str(temp_value[outside]) + " F")
        temperatureGg.set(str(temp_value[garage]) + " F")
        temperatureUp.set(str(temp_value[upstairs]) + " F")
        temperatureDn.set(str(temp_value[basement]) + " F")
        temperatureSammyDoor.set(str(temp_value[sammyDoor]) + " F")
        timeStamp.set(str(dateTime_value))
        avg = format(float(((float(temp_value[livingRoom]) + float(temp_value[upstairs])) / 2.0)), '.1f')
        mainTempValue.set(str(avg) + " F")

    except:
        pass

    root.after(2000, updateTemps)


def getDoors():
    global garageOpenIcon
    global garageClosedIcon
    global doorOpenIcon
    global doorUnlockedIcon
    global doorLockedIcon

    global mainDoorLabel
    global sideDoorLabel

#   sideDoorState = 0
#   mainDoorState = 0
    #side door open and unlocked:
    if(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
#       sideDoorState = 2
        sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorOpenIcon)


    #closed and unlocked:
    elif(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.LOW):
        if(GPIO.input(sideDoorLockPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
#           sideDoorState = 1
            sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorUnlockedIcon)

        elif(GPIO.input(sideDoorPin) == GPIO.LOW):
#           sideDoorState = 0
            sideDoorLabel = Label(image = doorLockedIcon)

    #main door:
    if(GPIO.input(mainDoorPin) == GPIO.HIGH):
#       mainDoorState = 1
        mainDoorLabel = Label(image = garageOpenIcon)

    else:
        mainDoorState = 0
        mainDoorLabel = Label(image = garageClosedIcon)

    mainDoorLabel.place(x = 50, y = 400)
    sideDoorLabel.place(x = 150, y = 400)

    root.after(1000, getDoors)


def getTime():
    currentTime.set(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    root.after(500, getTime)

root.after(1000, getTime)
root.after(1001, updateTemps)
root.after(1000, getDoors)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This seems to have way more code than is necessary for the purposes of this question. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. As per requested, relevant code is included at the top and full code at bottom.

Comment: We don't need the full code. We need a _minimal_ example that illustrates only the very specific thing you're asking about.

Comment: As I stated, theres both. Do you want me to remove the full version? The truncated version should be enough to replicate the issue.

Comment: If the minimal code is sufficient to reproduce the problem then there's no need for the full code.

Comment: Ok, ill delete the full code. Any suggestions on why the images are flickering?

Comment: I don't know. I can't run your code. It's probably because you are creating a new label ever second instead of re-using the existing label.

Comment: I found that the same thing happened with text labels when i'd change something other than the text inside it. If i wanted to make it red in one situation and white in another the same thing happened. I couldnt get it to work at all unless I specified a whole new label. I tried making the color a variable but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

maindoorlabel.configure(image = garageopenicon)
maindoorlabel.image = garageopenicon worked.